# using IPv6 and IPv4 at the same application

Tags: c++, ipv6, ipv4

I have a SNMP Manager written in C++ using the MG Soft SDK. Till now it only sends Get and receives Trap with IPv4. Now a second SNMP Agent shall be connected but this one has IPv6. Is it possible with one application to get a connection to one remote system with IPv4 and to another one with IPv6 at the same time with the same networkcard? or do I need 2 networkcards, one for IPv4 and the other for IPv6?

Comment: IPv4 and IPv6 are completely separate protocols that are not aware of the other. You could run a variety of network protocols, e.g. IPv4, IPv6, IPX, AppleTalk, etc., all at the same time on the same network interface.

Comment: The real question is whether the "MG Soft SDK" (whatever that is) offers clean enough APIs to have both. Is there a tag that would get the attention of MG Soft SDK specialists?

Comment: Given that the SDK headers are not even available for download without jumping through "evaluate our product" hoops, I doubt you'll get a better answer than "One NIC, two connections (IPV4 and IPV6) is fine, unless the API is really crappy". And if the API is crappy, the second NIC might not even help :-)

Comment: thank you for the answers. that helps me. the sdk if for SNMP implementations and it supports v4 and v6

Comment: One convenient way to support both IPv4 and IPv6 (on OS's with dual-stack capability, which is to say most of them) is to port your program to use IPv6, then do a `setsockopt(IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, &myFalseValue, sizeof(myFalseValue))` on your IPv6-socket(s).   Now you have a socket that can be connected to any IPv6 address (in which case it will use IPv6) or any IPv4-mapped IPv6 address (in which case the socket will use IPv4 internally but still look like an IPv6 socket to your program).  This simplifies your program greatly, since you only need one codepath instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You just need to open 2 separate connections from within your application - one using IPv4, the other using IPv6 (of course this requires you to implement support for both IPv4 and IPv6 protocols in your application).

It works the same way as if you wanted to open multiple IPv4 connections from within the same application.

For instace, web browsers open separate connections for separate webpages you visit. They, of course, can connect to one web server using IPv4, while at the same time being connected to another web server via IPv6.

Comment: Actually, web browsers usually open multiple connections per page, and some can be IPv4, while others are IPv6 for the same page. Different page elements can be fetch by differen IP versions. There are browser plugins that will show you that.